# Left align ul inside CSS grid

Tags: css

[image]I am trying to left align a list inside a css grid.  However, the text-align and setting the margins and padding don't seem to work. How can I left align the ul list. Codepen: https://codepen.io/centem/pen/oNvZLgP Thankyou.

```
ul {
  list-style: none;
  text-align: left;
}

li {
  padding-left: 0;
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Comment: There's no `ul` in your codepen. If the example only involves HTML & CSS then please make a code snippet here, in your question itself

Comment: I added a print screen of the codepen showing the ul and li elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the below CSS

```
ul{
  padding-left: 2%; 
}
```

You can accordingly change the padding value depending upon the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Also if you want your list items completely aligned to the left, get rid of the following `padding` line under the `.grid-page > div` selector:

```
padding: 0px 20px;
```

Comment: Max, neither worked. Please see codepen. I updated with the adjustments but li still show to the right.

Answer (score 0):

To complete Not A Bot's answer (it's always good to know why something works), the reason behind your issue was the default padding of unordered lists.

[UL Default CSS Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pNg0U.png)

These values are there to make lists look like written documents lists but obviously, that's not what we want in many cases.

Usually, margins and paddings of  elements should be reset. In your case:

```
ul {
  padding: 0;
}
```

should be enough, since you're already setting a padding for the container.